# Which ionic radius is most relevant for anticipating co-crystalization?

Tags: elements, atomic-structure, crystallography, atomic-radius, recrystallization

In the context of anticipating the likeliness that elemental impurities co-crystalize into the crystals containing an element of similar radius (see [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/166552/what-are-good-ways-to-anticipate-co-crystalization-of-different-metal-ions?noredirect=1#comment346854_166552)), which is the relevant radii to consider?

1. Is it the crystal ionic radii or the  effective ionic radii in pm of elements as a function of ionic charge and spin?

AND

2. Is it the low spin or the high spin radius of an element that should be considered?